# Маген Давид: правильное написание и ударение

Tags: орфоэпия, прописная-строчная, слитно-раздельно, заимствования, транскрипция

Мне встречались(в книгах и на сайтах) самые различные варианты:
***магендавид, могендавид, могендовид, Маген Давид, маген-Давид*** и проч.

Подскажите, как это слово правильно пишется? И на какой слог нужно ставить ударение? Вероятно, на последний?

Comment: Что это форум в последнее время потянуло в еврейскую тему? К чему бы это ))  Вот меня уже тянет отвечать вопросом на вопрос...

Comment: Не знаю, я не слежу за последними сообщениями. Лично я задала два вопроса на еврейскую тематику: об этимологии и написании слова кипеш (причём о еврейских корнях этого слова я не знала) и этот. Уже не надеюсь, правда, на чей-нибудь ответ. Никто, похоже, не скажет. :(

Comment: Попробую ответить... т.к. других желающих подставиться не нашлось...

Comment: Вы предлагаете убрать в метках "слитно-раздельно" и вменить "транскрипцию и заимствование". Автор на ЭТОМ, собственно, не заострял свое внимание. Или?..

Comment: Я не хотел убрать метку слитно-раздельно - но иначе не удаётся вставить транскрипцию. Требуется не более 5 меток. Если вы можете, верните слитно-раздельно. Мне кажется что правильная метка этого вопроса - произношение и написание иностранного/заимствованного выражения.

Comment: @Ольга, ответы здесь не даются в режиме онлайна. Иногда и через несколько лет отвечают, вам надо бы терпения набраться.

Answer (score 2):

Из более или менее авторитетных иточников:

Звезда Дави́да (ивр. ‏מָגֵן דָּוִד‏‎ — Маге́н Дави́д, «Щит Давида»; в идише произносится могендо́вид) — древний символ, эмблема в форме шестиконечной звезды (гексаграммы), в которой два одинаковых равносторонних треугольника (один развёрнут вершиной вверх, другой — вершиной вниз) наложены друг на друга, образуя структуру из шести одинаковых углов, присоединённых к сторонам правильного шестиугольника. ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0))

МАГЕ́Н-ДАВИ́Д (מָגֵן דָוִד, `щит Давида`), шестиконечная звезда (гексаграмма), образованная двумя равносторонними треугольниками с общим центром, ориентированными противоположно друг другу. ([Электронная еврейская энцикопедия](http://www.eleven.co.il/article/12556))

Многие ученые полагают, что именно благодаря караимам шестиконечный Щит Давида ― Маген Давид ― стал общеупотребительным еврейским символом. [Михаэль Дорфман. Еврейские фрагменты жития святителя Никиты (2003) // Интернет-альманах «Лебедь», 2003.12.07] ([Нацкорпус](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%E0%E3%E5%ED%20%E4%E0%E2%E8%E4&mode=main))

Comment: В "авторитетном" источнике нет как минимум указания на двойное ударение м**о**генд**о**вид. А самое главное, они не дают ответа на вопрос, как надо произносить и **писать**это на русском.

Comment: @Мимоходов, Они же пишут по-русски и ставят ударение - так и надо писать и произносить (если им верить, конечно, но лучшего ничего не удалось найти)

Answer (score 1):

В современном варианте (напр., израильское радио) — гласные произносятся как **А** и ударение — на последний слог. Пишется "магендавид" или "маген-Давид" (т.к. Давид — имя собственное).
Другой вариант: м**о**генд**о**вид — с **о**канием и ударением на 1-й и 3-й слог — характерен для религиозных евреев европейского происхождения (которые в шляпах и все в чёрном). По историческим причинам.
У евреев разных национальностей "религиозное" произношение различается, и, если кто-то уверен, что их произношение единственно верное, лучше с ними не спорить.

Comment: Извините, свой текст случайно внес в ваш ответ. Откатил.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку слово заимствованное, к тому же имя собственное, а словарной фиксации нет, то и говорить о единственной правильности не приходится.
Мне на слух ближе "могедовид" (причем с очень слабым, совсем не характерным для русского  "в", - почти что "могендойид"), но я против - и неоднократно уже спорил даже здесь на эту тему - прямого перенесения каких-то свойств одного языка на другой. Тем более надо различать произношение и написание. К тому же особенности иврита и его графики просто не позволяют дать однозначный ответ по части написания огласовок.

Единственный сколько-нибудь серьезный аргумент здесь то, что слово обозначает некое историческое (или легендарно-историческое) понятие. В таких случаях уместнее использовать исторически закрепленный вариант, т. е. **Могендовид** - с двумя ударными о и заглавной на письме. Но насколько этот аргумент убедителен для носителей современного языка, сказать не берусь. Тем более "могендовид" - это скорее идиш, а исторические легенды, как вы понимаете, связывают символ с временами, когда говорили на иврите...  В общем путаница тут изрядная. Будем ждать словарной фиксации.

Comment: На иврите и говорили и до сих пор говорят)) поэтому первый и рекомендуемый вариант у меня - "израильское радио". Всяких диалектов слишком много))

Comment: @ddbug говорят, не спорю. Только современный иврит еще дальше от исторического, чем, скажем, современный новогреческий от древнегреческого, из которого мы много чего позаимствовали. Вы логику мою не поняли. Заимствование не меняется вместе с языком-источником.

Comment: @Мимоходов Раз словарной фиксации нет, то логично ориентироваться на современный иврит: именно он сейчас цитируется в российских новостях, и современное произношение скорее всего станет словарным.

Comment: @Мимоходов, уважаемый, кто же спорит. Мы и пятиконечную звезду позаимствовали. Но вопрос был не что это, не откуда произошло, а просто как сказать и написать.

Comment: Мимоходов, М_Г и ddbug, спасибо!!!